# Set the first option select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I want to set the first position to select2 dropdown by default, I have tried this but It doens´t work:

```
$('#mylist').val($('#mylist option:first-child').val()).trigger('change');
```

Other way that I tried;

```
$('#mylist').val(1);
```

But the problem is I don´t know what value is, because it is depend from a query and It will not always be the same value.

I did not set the dropdown values ​​from the HTML, but it is an input hidden and the values ​​are loaded in a query

I hope that anyone can help me

Regards!

Comment: Can you provide some ```HTML```?

Comment: do you want the first element to be selected by default?

Comment: $('#mylist option:eq(0)').prop('selected',true)

Comment: Yes It is @Imprfectluck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery select2 set default value from an option in list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969666/jquery-select2-set-default-value-from-an-option-in-list)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you using Select2 4.x just  trigger `change.select2`

```
$('#mylist').val(1).trigger('change.select2');
```

Comment: I use select2 3.5x

Answer (score 10):

please try with this:

```
$('#yourSelect2').val($('#yourSelect2 option:eq(1)').val()).trigger('change');
```

the value from **eq()** depends of the position that you want to select

Answer (score 8):

This works for me:

```
$('#mylist option:eq(0)').prop('selected',true);
```

Comment: @stephen-rauch .trigger('change') should be added else not working

Comment: @AliKaraca, I did not write the answer, I am only the editor.

Answer (score 3):

Please do this

```
$('select#mylist').val(1).select2();
```

Comment: This answer works great if u don't need to refresh something like datatable. Nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use attribute specifiers and set that element's `selected` prop to `true` like so:

```js
$('option[value="op2"]').prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="list">
  <option value="op1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="op2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="op3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="op4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Then change `op2` to whatever the `value` attribute of the desired default option is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem is that the dropdown is filled with a query

Answer (score 2):

this work for me :

```
$("#mylist").val($("#mylist option:first").val()).trigger('change');
```

juste remove `-child`

Answer (score 0):

As you may know Select2 need data in particular format only `[id="id_value",text="data_linked_to_id"]`

Lets consider you want to select first item ,you should have its Id which is used by select2 to list all items.(let here first id be 1)

> $('#selectElementId').val("1");
> $('#selectElementId').trigger('change');

If want to set multiple items selected then pass array of ids.
ids=["1","3","4"]

> $("#selectElementId").val(ids);
> $("#selectElementId").trigger('change');

```
           **OR**
```

> $("#selectElementId").val(["1","3","4"]);
> $("#selectElementId").trigger('change');

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**
Select first option of your select(s) - works not only for select2

```
$('#myForm').find('select').find('option:eq(0)').attr('selected','selected');
```

**Step 2:**
Trigger select2 change

```
$('#myForm select').trigger('change.select2');
```