# Angularjs Directive Select2 code

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-select2

I see the following code in a directive for our project, but am not sure what it does.  Can someone explain what the first line does?  Is this just how select2 is initiated?

```
 element.select2('val', ngModel.$viewValue);
                    if (isOpen) {
                        element.select2("close").select2("open");
                    }
```

Comment: It's basically setting a new value for select2,which can be done by using trigger too.

Comment: hey @NamdeoKarande, can you explain that a little bit?  What is 'val'?  I don't see it declared anywhere in the code.  Also is $viewValue used as a filter for search?  Thanks.

Comment: 'val' is something where you tell select2 to update the value of dropdown.For more details refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969666/jquery-select2-set-default-value-from-an-option-in-list  . Whereas $viewValue is to get the string value of the model.For more details refer this -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383812/whats-the-difference-between-ngmodel-modelvalue-and-ngmodel-viewvalue