# how to by default selected the dropdown value of select2.js

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-select2

I have used the `select2.js` library for dropdown list in my code. I want to select the dropdown value deafult as per the value get from my url. I have no idea how to do that thing in `select.js`.

Here in below code `var e` I get the value which I want to selected.
Javascript code:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
     var url = window.location.href;
     var a = url.split('=');
     var b = a[2];
     var d = b.split('_');
     var e =d[1];
     $("#Address1").select2({

        })

   });
```

HTML code:

```
<select class="ct-select-lg" id="Address" name="Address[]">
                            </select>
```

In these code i get the data from my API:

```
$("#Address").select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "url",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
      return {
        q: params.term,
        page: params.page
      };
    },
    processResults: function (data, params) {
    return {
        results: data.items,

      };
    },
    cache: true
  },
  placeholder: 'Search for a repository',
  escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
  minimumInputLength: 1,

});
```

Comment: Please, see this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969666/jquery-select2-set-default-value-from-an-option-in-list

Comment: i tried these but it is not working

Comment: have you tried with $('#Address').val(defaultValue).trigger('change');

Comment: yes i already tried these

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery select2 set default value from an option in list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969666/jquery-select2-set-default-value-from-an-option-in-list)

Comment: i want to selected the value according the value which i get from url

Answer (score 0):

As, per your last comment I hope your URL be like `http://localhost/test/?test=1`. So, by what I understand I created some code, this will get value from the url and then set value for the select.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="select2-4.0.6-rc.1/dist/css/select2.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="select2-4.0.6-rc.1/dist/js/select2.js"></script>
    <script>
        var url = window.location.href;
        var selected = (url.split('?')[1]).split('=')[1]
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('#select').select2();
            jQuery('#select').val(selected).trigger('change');
        })
    </script>
    <select style="width:100px;" id="select">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
```

**NOTE:** You have to add path of `select2` as per your local directories.